# How to restore WhatsApp data from SD card or internal memory and not from Google Drive?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery, restore

I changed phones and installed WhatsApp on the new one. I have a backup database file on an SD card and the same file copied to the internal WhatsApp folder and Google Drive.
However, during install, the restore process only checks in G Drive and says that no backup is available.

How do I restore the data from this backup file from the internal memory or SD card? There is no corresponding option during backup restore.

Adding a few points based on other QnA I went through. Hope they help.

1. The phone number has not changed. I am using the same number on the new phone as earlier.
2. I have copied the backup database file from the SD card to the internal memory and also to the G Drive
3. The backup file is named "msgstore.db.crypt12" It does not have the date in the name.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with this too, and today finally it worked.  Unfortunately I'm not sure which of the following additional steps did the trick, but maybe it helps others:

1. I copied the *entire* WhatsApp folder over from the old phone to the new one (zipped it using Total Commander, copied it to a PC via USB, copied it to the new phone also via USB, unzipped it also using Total Commander).
2. After installing WhatsApp, I gave the app all possible permissions *before* running it: under Settings/Apps, select WhatsApp, tap Permissions, and then select all permissions listed under "denied" and tap "allow" (you can revoke the permissions again after the backup is succesfully restored).

After doing this, running WhatsApp and confirming my phone number, I was finally prompted to restore the local backup. Before that, WhatsApp asked me for some permissions and then asked me to select a Google Drive backup (which I hadn't done), when I selected "skip" at this step it apparently also skipped the local backup.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open google drive.
2. Top left menu, backups, **deactivate** WhatsApp backup
   (option to delete also, not necessary)
3. Re-do the login procedure as usual.
   Done.