# How to restore whatsapp data from local storage?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, internal-storage, restore

I have tried multiple options to restore data from internal storage. Unfortunately, none of them has been successful. Every time I get prompted to google drive back up even though I don't have any backup on google drive and I have disconnected WhatsApp from my google drive accounts. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you tried the step mentioned on [WhatsApp Help Center](https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/chats/how-to-restore-your-chat-history)?

Comment: yes its not helpful

Comment: There are similar questions asked already, and the most recent answer is to disable WhatsApp backup from Google Drive first: [1](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216614/44325), [2](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209121/44325). There's also the older approach mentioned on [3](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203523/44325). Please try and let us know if any of it works. Thanks.