# Whatsapp not doing local backup restore! (not Google Drive)

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, restore

Today I decided to reset the phone. I got all my backups. At the same time, I copied all the files of WhatsApp to my computer completely. now i copied Whatsapp folder to phone memory. I installed Whatsapp, I got a message on my number, then I gave permission to google drive for backups (I only store my backups locally, not on google drive) .. but no restore notification came. I don't have any messages! please help me what should i do

EDIT
When I uninstall and reinstall WhatsApp, the question 'Do you have a backup in google drive' appears. my whatsapp chat backup is locally on my phone. I tried every way. after installing i removed all google accounts, i copied whatsapp backups folder to both sd card and internal storage but it doesn't look at local backups...
please we need urgent support!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, have you followed the steps given on [the official WhatsApp Help Center](https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/chats/how-to-restore-your-chat-history)?

Comment: Of course I tried.  The problem is that while whatsapp is re-installing, it only looks at google drive.  passes without looking at local backups
 https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsapp/comments/np2zjp/how_to_restore_from_whatsapp_local_backup_not/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Comment: There are similar questions asked already, and the most recent answer is to disable WhatsApp backup from Google Drive first: [1](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216614/44325), [2](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209121/44325). There's also the older approach mentioned on [3](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203523/44325). Please try and let us know if any of it works. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried all of these. it would also be approved if it worked. other than that, I installed the old whatsapp version (version 2.19.351) it said 'you have a local backup' (finally) but it didn't work this time. There is a really serious problem. I removed all my google accounts and did everything @AndrewT.

Comment: @AndrewT. Are you going to help me? I reset my phone. and now I want to do everything properly. Please help me.
 [a forum site](https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?showtopic=186375&st=47660#entry107121411)

Comment: Sorry @theoyuncu8, I don't think I can help further. Looks like this is a relatively new issue since this site got the same questions recently. Hopefully others can help, and if you found the solution, feel free to also share it here.

Comment: A new topic has just been opened. I can't comment because I don't have 50 reputation but this problem is really starting to get serious. What can we do? Please guide us. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/237495/whatsapp-cannot-restore-from-a-local-backup

Comment: Once OTP is verified, turn off intenet. This will force WhatsApp to look for local backup.

Comment: @defalt unfortunately. that didn't work either. Does it work on older versions according to what those who tried it said? Current Version: 2.21.10.16 Working Versions:  2.21.9.5, 2.21.8.17

Answer (score 0):

Please install WhatsApp version 2.21.8.17 and try again. It did the job for me.