# Whatsapp - Cannot restore from a local backup

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, restore

today I made a mistake on my Samsung Galaxy note 10+ Phone: my daughter deleted the app.
When I took the phone back, I noticed that whatsapp was no longer more installed on my phone.

When I reinstalled it from play store, activated, it can't find any backup, even if I have daily backup on my phone.

I've a lot of files in my whatsapp chat history and I reinstalled several times, following also the steps described in this guide: [WhatsApp doesn't prompt to restore from local storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203523/whatsapp-doesnt-prompt-to-restore-from-local-storage), but none of the solutions provided (permissions, etc.) works.

At first startup, Whatsapp asks for the permission to access google drive and then, it asks for the name to display, skipping the backup. Please note that i never changed my phone number, etc.

I tried also on Xiaomi Redmi Note 7, that I just initialized for this purpose.
I copied all the whatsapp data folder, renamed the appropriate msgstore.db.crypt14 but whatsapp didn't ask for any restore.

At this point, after several retries, Whatsapp activation system let me wait 24 hours or days to receive a new activation code by text message or call.

I've all of my working history and backed up whatsapp folder several times, during years but I never experienced a behaviour like that.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Digitalchild

Answer (score 2):

With A11 WhatsApp new location is

```
/sdcard/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/DataBases
```

Try to copy DBs to here